# How to ignore mismatched tags while parsing xml in Python

Tags: python, xml, sax, expat-parser

I want to parse an XML file with Python. I don't need the hierarchical tag structure -- all I want is a simple SAX or Expat-based parser. However, they both fail with `mismatched tag`-related error messages when the XML file is not well formed.

Is there a way to tell the parser to ignore these errors? I tried to

```
parser.setFeature(sax.handler.feature_validation, False)
```

, but that didn't help either.

Is there a solution? Either SAX/Expat would do.

Comment: Try to avoid calling it XML when it isn't. There's no such thing as "an XML file that is not well formed" - if it's not well-formed, then it isn't XML. And basically, if you don't want to follow the XML rules, then you need to say what rules you do want to follow. If it's a random sequence of characters then the only thing the parser can sensibly deliver is a random sequence of characters.

Answer (score 0):

You should give [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) a try.  Its main purpose is to parse HTML even in the presence of malformations.   You may find it parses your invalid XML without much trouble.

Comment: As far as I remember, it doesn't offer a sequential (SAX-like) interface?

Comment: @DavidNemeskey: I don't know if it will help in your particular case, but check out SoupStrainer: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#Fun%20With%20SoupStrainers

Answer (score 0):

Would you also use lxml? It has a function called `iterparse`, which is event-driven parsing in a (according to the documentation) "SAX-like fashion", and has a parameter to force parsing broken input. It's fairly easy to use, also.

[lxml iterparse tutorial](http://lxml.de/parsing.html#iterparse-and-iterwalk)

[lxml iterparse class definition](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree.iterparse-class.html)